# Rails JQuery Ajax call succeeds, but js.erb data is not rendered unless I include unwanted characters

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

I am trying to set up a select input that will populate a div with data pulled by an ajax call when the select input is changed.

I have verified in the logs that the ajax call is successful and the js.erb file is being rendered, however whether the content of the js.erb file actually shows up in the target div seems to depend on whether I include certain characters in the js.erb file. I can't wrap my head around why this might be, and I can't get the specific data I want to display without also including unwanted characters.

**View:**

```
      <div id="gl"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :fc %>
        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.collection_select :fc, Location.active, :location_name, :location_name, {prompt: true}, {required: true, class: 'form-control input-sm'} %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**View Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#idle_asset_fc").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<%= get_gl_prefix_ajax_path %>", 
                data: "fc=" + $("#idle_asset_fc").val(),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#gl").html(data);
                }
            });

        });
```

**Controller:**

```
def get_gl_prefix_ajax
    @result = Location.location_name(params[:fc]).pluck(:gl_prefix)[0]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

**Examples of get_gl_prefix_ajax.js.erb that successfully alter the div:**

Adding double or single quotes around my erb tags allows it to be added to the div, and adding double forward slashes also allow the data to be added, however the quotes and slashes also show up, which is not desired

```
'<%= @result %>' <!-- results in '01.1234', including the quotes -->
//<%= @result %>  <!-- results in //01.1234, including the forward slashes -->
```

**This is what I want, but it isn't added to the div without the above characters:**

```
<%= @result %> <!-- should result in 01.2345 -->
```

It may also be worth mentioning that plain text won't be added without the quotes or forward slashes either. Also, adding anything outside of the quotes or not directly behind the double forward slashes will result in nothing being added to the div.

I have tried wrapping my code in escape_javascript, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Representative log entry:

```
Mon Dec 05 19:16:48 2016 GMT  26728....com:0 [INFO] (null):0 (null)(): (null): Started GET "/get_gl_prefix_ajax?fc=ILA11" for 1...9 at 2016-12-05 19:16:48 +0000
Mon Dec 05 19:16:48 2016 GMT  26728....com:0 [INFO] (null):0 (null)(): (null): Processing by LocationsController#get_gl_prefix_ajax as */*
Mon Dec 05 19:16:48 2016 GMT  26728....com:0 [INFO] (null):0 (null)(): (null):   Parameters: {"fc"=>"ILA11"}
Mon Dec 05 19:16:48 2016 GMT  26728....com:0 [DEBUG] (null):0 (null)(): (null):    (12.3ms)  SELECT `locations`.`gl_prefix` FROM `locations` WHERE (location_name = 'ILA11')
Mon Dec 05 19:16:48 2016 GMT  26728....com:0 [INFO] (null):0 (null)(): (null):   Rendered locations/get_gl_prefix_ajax.js.erb (0.4ms)
Mon Dec 05 19:16:48 2016 GMT  26728....com:0 [INFO] (null):0 (null)(): (null): Completed 200 OK in 126ms (Views: 2.2ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
```

Any idea what is going on, and how can I simply display the data I want without the unwanted characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, when you do this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

It means you are returning Javascript in the response, not HTML directly. Hence, when you wrap it in quotes or start with `//`, it interprets it as Javascript string or comment line.

There are two ways to fix it.

1. **The RJS Way**

   Remove following `success` block from your JQuery code:

   ```
   success: function(data){
     $("#gl").html(data);
   }
   ```

   Add Javascript in `get_gl_prefix_ajax.js.erb` file, which is what its meant for. It would look like this:

   ```
   $("#gl").html('<%= result %>');
   ```
2. **The JSON Way**

   The other option is to return your data in JSON format from the controller, and then in `success` callback for `$.ajax`, parse the JSON data and convert it into HTML before inserting in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the cleanest way buy you can use the `parseFloat()` function on the js string to convert it from a string to a float

Comment: Thanks, but its the weirdness of why it won't display my data without the extra characters I am concerned about, not the data type. I am just displaying it on the page so it is fine that it is a string.